# How can i smooth the animation?

Tags: html, css

I want the animation for the conic-gradient smooth like the left side box. I did almost all the same things for these two box to be animated except that the box1 is using transform:rotate() property for animation and box2 is using conic-gradient for animation but box2 is not giving smooth transition like box1.
how can i do that??

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;

}
.box1, .box2{
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: conic-gradient(black 0deg, black 10deg, white 0deg);
}
@keyframes box1{
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.box1{
  margin-right: 10px;
  animation-name: box1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes box2{
  0% {background-image: conic-gradient(black 0deg, black 10deg, white 0deg);}
  100% {background-image: conic-gradient(black 0deg, black 300deg, white 0deg);}
}

.box2{
  margin-left: 10px;
  animation-name: box2;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>animation</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="box1">
   </div>
   <div class="box2">

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

want smooth transition animation like the box1.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using an [`@property` at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property) to register a custom CSS property with certain parameters to make it available for interpolation for animations. Then, change this property in the `@keyframes`.

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;

}
.box1, .box2{
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: conic-gradient(black 0deg, black 10deg, white 0deg);
}
@keyframes box1{
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.box1{
  margin-right: 10px;
  animation-name: box1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@property --angle {
  syntax: "<angle>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0deg;
}

@keyframes box2{
  0% {
    --angle: 0deg;
  }
  100% {
    --angle: 300deg;
  }
}

.box2{
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-image: conic-gradient(black 0deg, black var(--angle), white 0deg);
  animation-name: box2;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>animation</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="box1">
   </div>
   <div class="box2">

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please be aware that as of time of writing, [Firefox does not yet support the `@property` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property#browser_compatibility).

Comment: thanks for the info. i am running firefox and thats why the animation was not working even after using @property. so the best way is to use javascript for all browsers?